# Designing a role based access control with support for relations

Tags: database, access-control, rbac

I'm Designing a DB Model for an access control system which is in part role based but does require some access list functionality and relational access.

I'm building a web app (with PHP if it matters and MVC architecture) for a school to manage students, teachers, staff and manager interactions such as a teacher rewarding a student or one of the staff enrolling or removing a student. My main problem is that I am asked to:
1- provide optional extra permissions for each user other than what they already inherit from their role/roles. (=>Access List)
2- provide an easy way to match certain students to certain students each term, meaning that one teacher should be able to score students who attend a class he teaches but not other students in other classes, and this classes change too often (2 months between each change).

I am thinking of Implementing a standard role based system, add an extra table for extra permissions per user and an extra field in permissions called scope which can be optionally filled with the name of another table (this is done by the app not db) which contains a list of connections. for example a teacher can have teacher controller: 'scoring' -> method 'new score' -> scope: 'course-user' which means that I search in a 'course-user' table for the teacher id and any other userid with the same courseid and give the teacher permission to submit new score for any student sharing the courseid with the teacher. this is my Model:
[image: My Current DB Structure]

Is this the right way to go? should I create new table for every new shared connection or put them all in one table? I appreciate any help or at least direction towards a standard solution to this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't implement a DB model for access control. Your DB model should have the objects you care about (students, teachers, classes...). The rest should be expressed as policies in an **externalized authorization** model. This is called **Attribute-Based Access Control** [abac](/questions/tagged/abac). It's also known as policy-based access control (PBAC). Different names, same thing.

In ABAC, you have attributes on the one hand (the fields of your tables in your DB model e.g. username, role, course year...) and policies on the other. For instance:

- Teachers can edit the grade of a student in a class they teach
- Students can view their own grades
- A student can view the course material of a class they belong to

All these are examples of (business) authorization policies.

In ABAC, you then have the notion of a Policy Decision Point (PDP) which evaluates authorization policies and a Policy Enforcement Point (PEP) which intercepts business requests and sends off authorization requests to the PDP. For instance:

- Can Alice the student view grade #123?
- Can Bob the teacher view the profile of student Alice?

The PDP replies with a decision, either Permit or Deny, which the PEP must then enforce. You mention that you have an MVC model for your application. Your PEP would likely be an interceptor or annotation in your controller layer.

[image: ABAC Architecture]

There are several ABAC languages and implementations out there:

- open-source:

  - Open Policy Agent based on the Rego language
  - AuthZForce based on the XACML standard.
- closed-source: Axiomatics Policy Server based on the XACML and ALFA standards.